# Swift 5 - Timer not re-starting

Tags: swift

I want to animate the drawing of a custom view using Timer.scheduleTimer.

The problem is that after hitting the button that starts the animation a couple of times - after the previous animation finishes - the timer does not start again. The code that should start it is called but the block of the timer is not called once.

I have no clue why XD

Here are the relevant parts of my code.

**In ViewController**

```
self.customView.playAnimation(completion: {
        //Re arrange the things to be drawn in custom view
    })
```

**In Custom View**

```
private var drawingPercenatge: Double = -1 /* -1 if inactive, otherwise between 0 (inclusive) and 100 (inclusive) */ {
    didSet {
        if drawingPercenatge > 100 {
            drawingPercenatge = 100
        }
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

/*...*/

public func playAnimation(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    if self.animationActive { return }
    
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    self.animationActive = true
    
    Animator().animateValue(duration: 0.5, fps: 30, easing: .easeInCubic, setValue: { percentage in
        self.drawingPercenatge = percentage
    }, setNeutralState: {
        self.drawingPercenatge = -1
        
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.animationActive = false
        completion()
    })
}

/*...*/

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    
    //Draw but wiht respect to drawingPercenatge if != -1
}
```

In Animator

```
//Duration in seconds
public func animateValue(duration: Double, fps: Double = 30, easing: EasingFunction = .linear, setValue: @escaping (_ percentage: Double) -> Void, setNeutralState: @escaping () -> Void) {
    var elapsedPerecntage: Double = 0 // 0 <-> 100
    
    //Set initial state
    setValue(elapsedPerecntage)
    
    var elapsedTime: Double = 0 //seconds
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1 / fps, repeats: true, block: { animationTimer in
        elapsedPerecntage += 100 / (fps * duration)
        
        //Set state
        setValue(self.warpProgress(percentage: elapsedPerecntage, for: easing))
        
        elapsedTime += 1 / fps
        
        if elapsedPerecntage >= 100 {
            animationTimer.invalidate()
            setNeutralState()
        }
    })
}

private func warpProgress(percentage: Double, for easingFunction: EasingFunction) -> Double {
    let x = percentage / 100
    
    switch easingFunction {
    //Linear
    case .linear:
        return x * 100
    //Quint
    case .easeInQuint:
        return (x * x * x * x * x) * 100
    case .easeInOutQuint:
        return (x < 0.5 ? 16 * x * x * x * x * x : 1 - pow(-2 * x + 2, 5) / 2) * 100
    //Cubic
    case .easeInCubic:
        return (x * x * x) * 100
    case .easeInOutCubic:
        return (x < 0.5 ? 4 * x * x * x : 1 - pow(-2 * x + 2, 3) / 2) * 100
    //Sine
    case .easeInOutSine:
        return (-(cos(Double.pi * x) - 1) / 2) * 100
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't store the result of Timer. So it will be released. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-make-an-action-repeat-using-timer

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. But what do I do now?

Comment: If you are trying to update the screen with great frequency (e.g. to manually animate), I would advise against `Timer` and would instead suggest [`CADisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink/) a special type of timer that has been specifically designed for optimal screen refresh rates. Also, I would advise against this manual calculation of elapsed as `elapsedTime += 1 + fps` and instead look at the time (e.g. `CACurrentMediaTime()` or the display link’s timestamp properties).

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you so much for your answer. I am now using CADisplayLink. However I still have the same problem. Sometimes the playMorphLinesIntoPointAnimation is being called just once and the app completely freezes. Without any "trying to break it" behaviour. What the hell is going on? However, something I noticed is that I can't seem to reproduce it on the simulator. Does that make any sense?